# Bokeh: Donut Chart, change default size

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

If I am not wrong Donut charts are the only ones with an already set default size of 400. So if I set the size of my plot to be anything less than 400, the donut cuts off the top and bottom of plot. How do I change the size of the donut as well

Code:

```
arr = [1,3,2,4]
data = pd.Series(arr, index=list('abcd'))
plot = Donut(data, plot_height=300)
show(plot)
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xppo.png)

Comment: I have tried the resize tool and though it works I dont want the user to be using the tool everytime

Answer (score 1):

The `bokeh.charts` API, including `Donut` was deprecated and removed entirely in 2017. Instead, use the stable and supported `bokeh.plotting` API. In the `0.13.0` release you can do this:

```
from collections import Counter
from math import pi

import pandas as pd

from bokeh.palettes import Category20c
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.transform import cumsum

# Data

x = Counter({
    'United States': 157, 'United Kingdom': 93, 'Japan': 89, 'China': 63,
    'Germany': 44, 'India': 42, 'Italy': 40,'Australia': 35,
    'Brazil': 32, 'France': 31, 'Taiwan': 31,'Spain': 29
})

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(x), orient='index').reset_index().rename(index=str, columns={0:'value', 'index':'country'})
data['angle'] = data['value']/sum(x.values()) * 2*pi
data['color'] = Category20c[len(x)]

# Plotting code

p = figure(plot_height=350, title="Donut Chart", toolbar_location=None,
           tools="hover", tooltips=[("Country", "@country"),("Value", "@value")])

p.annular_wedge(x=0, y=1, inner_radius=0.2, outer_radius=0.4,
                start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),
                line_color="white", fill_color='color', legend='country', source=data)

p.axis.axis_label=None
p.axis.visible=False
p.grid.grid_line_color = None

show(p)
```

[image]